# How to read 向う?

Tags: kanji, okurigana

This is a sentence from 「ふたり」 by 赤川次郎

> 向うは、やっぱり寒い？

Does it read as むこう？If that is the case, then what is the difference between 向う and 向こう？

Comment: And むこう is pronounced ムコー.

Answer (score 1):

This is read as むこう.

向こう is the "standard" spelling, but people (especially novelists like him) sometimes use nonstandard or customary spellings like this.

You can see the list of such kanji here:

- [送り仮名の省略](http://takatakijou.web.fc2.com/okurigana.htm)
- [送り仮名の最短化](http://homepage3.nifty.com/jgrammar/ja/hyouk016.htm#okurigana_ue)

Comment: And 向う (read as むかう) is a verb meaning to face (something).